# ¿Cómo poner un texto en un efecto partículas?

Tags: jquery, css, particles

Tengo el siguiente problema, el cual realizo el efecto partículas/matrix, pero me gustaría posicionar un texto arriba del efecto. Intenté agregarlo y darle un `margin-top` para que bajara el texto, pero el problema es que que el efecto se baje.

¿Cómo sobreescribir en el mismo efecto un texto?

Mi codigo actual:

```js
/* -----------------------------------------------
/* Author : Vincent Garreau  - vincentgarreau.com
/* MIT license: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
/* GitHub : https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js
/* How to use? : Check the GitHub README
/* v1.0.3
/* ----------------------------------------------- */
function launchParticlesJS(a,e){var i=document.querySelector("#"+a+" > canvas");pJS={canvas:{el:i,w:i.offsetWidth,h:i.offsetHeight},particles:{color:"#fff",shape:"circle",opacity:1,size:2.5,size_random:true,nb:200,line_linked:{enable_auto:true,distance:100,color:"#fff",opacity:1,width:1,condensed_mode:{enable:true,rotateX:65000,rotateY:65000}},anim:{enable:true,speed:1},array:[]},interactivity:{enable:true,mouse:{distance:100},detect_on:"canvas",mode:"grab",line_linked:{opacity:1},events:{onclick:{enable:true,mode:"push",nb:4}}},retina_detect:false,fn:{vendors:{interactivity:{}}}};if(e){if(e.particles){var b=e.particles;if(b.color){pJS.particles.color=b.color}if(b.shape){pJS.particles.shape=b.shape}if(b.opacity){pJS.particles.opacity=b.opacity}if(b.size){pJS.particles.size=b.size}if(b.size_random==false){pJS.particles.size_random=b.size_random}if(b.nb){pJS.particles.nb=b.nb}if(b.line_linked){var j=b.line_linked;if(j.enable_auto==false){pJS.particles.line_linked.enable_auto=j.enable_auto}if(j.distance){pJS.particles.line_linked.distance=j.distance}if(j.color){pJS.particles.line_linked.color=j.color}if(j.opacity){pJS.particles.line_linked.opacity=j.opacity}if(j.width){pJS.particles.line_linked.width=j.width}if(j.condensed_mode){var g=j.condensed_mode;if(g.enable==false){pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.enable=g.enable}if(g.rotateX){pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateX=g.rotateX}if(g.rotateY){pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateY=g.rotateY}}}if(b.anim){var k=b.anim;if(k.enable==false){pJS.particles.anim.enable=k.enable}if(k.speed){pJS.particles.anim.speed=k.speed}}}if(e.interactivity){var c=e.interactivity;if(c.enable==false){pJS.interactivity.enable=c.enable}if(c.mouse){if(c.mouse.distance){pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance=c.mouse.distance}}if(c.detect_on){pJS.interactivity.detect_on=c.detect_on}if(c.mode){pJS.interactivity.mode=c.mode}if(c.line_linked){if(c.line_linked.opacity){pJS.interactivity.line_linked.opacity=c.line_linked.opacity}}if(c.events){var d=c.events;if(d.onclick){var h=d.onclick;if(h.enable==false){pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.enable=false}if(h.mode!="push"){pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.mode=h.mode}if(h.nb){pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.nb=h.nb}}}}pJS.retina_detect=e.retina_detect}pJS.particles.color_rgb=hexToRgb(pJS.particles.color);pJS.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line=hexToRgb(pJS.particles.line_linked.color);if(pJS.retina_detect&&window.devicePixelRatio>1){pJS.retina=true;pJS.canvas.pxratio=window.devicePixelRatio;pJS.canvas.w=pJS.canvas.el.offsetWidth*pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.canvas.h=pJS.canvas.el.offsetHeight*pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.particles.anim.speed=pJS.particles.anim.speed*pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.particles.line_linked.distance=pJS.particles.line_linked.distance*pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.particles.line_linked.width=pJS.particles.line_linked.width*pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance=pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance*pJS.canvas.pxratio}pJS.fn.canvasInit=function(){pJS.canvas.ctx=pJS.canvas.el.getContext("2d")};pJS.fn.canvasSize=function(){pJS.canvas.el.width=pJS.canvas.w;pJS.canvas.el.height=pJS.canvas.h;window.onresize=function(){if(pJS){pJS.canvas.w=pJS.canvas.el.offsetWidth;pJS.canvas.h=pJS.canvas.el.offsetHeight;if(pJS.retina){pJS.canvas.w*=pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.canvas.h*=pJS.canvas.pxratio}pJS.canvas.el.width=pJS.canvas.w;pJS.canvas.el.height=pJS.canvas.h;pJS.fn.canvasPaint();if(!pJS.particles.anim.enable){pJS.fn.particlesRemove();pJS.fn.canvasRemove();f()}}}};pJS.fn.canvasPaint=function(){pJS.canvas.ctx.fillRect(0,0,pJS.canvas.w,pJS.canvas.h)};pJS.fn.canvasRemove=function(){pJS.canvas.ctx.clearRect(0,0,pJS.canvas.w,pJS.canvas.h)};pJS.fn.particle=function(n,o,m){this.x=m?m.x:Math.random()*pJS.canvas.w;this.y=m?m.y:Math.random()*pJS.canvas.h;this.radius=(pJS.particles.size_random?Math.random():1)*pJS.particles.size;if(pJS.retina){this.radius*=pJS.canvas.pxratio}this.color=n;this.opacity=o;this.vx=-0.5+Math.random();this.vy=-0.5+Math.random();this.draw=function(){pJS.canvas.ctx.fillStyle="rgba("+this.color.r+","+this.color.g+","+this.color.b+","+this.opacity+")";pJS.canvas.ctx.beginPath();switch(pJS.particles.shape){case"circle":pJS.canvas.ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);break;case"edge":pJS.canvas.ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.radius*2,this.radius*2);break;case"triangle":pJS.canvas.ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y-this.radius);pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.radius,this.y+this.radius);pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(this.x-this.radius,this.y+this.radius);pJS.canvas.ctx.closePath();break}pJS.canvas.ctx.fill()}};pJS.fn.particlesCreate=function(){for(var m=0;m<pJS.particles.nb;m++){pJS.particles.array.push(new pJS.fn.particle(pJS.particles.color_rgb,pJS.particles.opacity))}};pJS.fn.particlesAnimate=function(){for(var n=0;n<pJS.particles.array.length;n++){var q=pJS.particles.array[n];q.x+=q.vx*(pJS.particles.anim.speed/2);q.y+=q.vy*(pJS.particles.anim.speed/2);if(q.x-q.radius>pJS.canvas.w){q.x=q.radius}else{if(q.x+q.radius<0){q.x=pJS.canvas.w+q.radius}}if(q.y-q.radius>pJS.canvas.h){q.y=q.radius}else{if(q.y+q.radius<0){q.y=pJS.canvas.h+q.radius}}for(var m=n+1;m<pJS.particles.array.length;m++){var o=pJS.particles.array[m];if(pJS.particles.line_linked.enable_auto){pJS.fn.vendors.distanceParticles(q,o)}if(pJS.interactivity.enable){switch(pJS.interactivity.mode){case"grab":pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.grabParticles(q,o);break}}}}};pJS.fn.particlesDraw=function(){pJS.canvas.ctx.clearRect(0,0,pJS.canvas.w,pJS.canvas.h);pJS.fn.particlesAnimate();for(var m=0;m<pJS.particles.array.length;m++){var n=pJS.particles.array[m];n.draw("rgba("+n.color.r+","+n.color.g+","+n.color.b+","+n.opacity+")")}};pJS.fn.particlesRemove=function(){pJS.particles.array=[]};pJS.fn.vendors.distanceParticles=function(t,r){var o=t.x-r.x,n=t.y-r.y,s=Math.sqrt(o*o+n*n);if(s<=pJS.particles.line_linked.distance){var m=pJS.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line;pJS.canvas.ctx.beginPath();pJS.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle="rgba("+m.r+","+m.g+","+m.b+","+(pJS.particles.line_linked.opacity-s/pJS.particles.line_linked.distance)+")";pJS.canvas.ctx.moveTo(t.x,t.y);pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(r.x,r.y);pJS.canvas.ctx.lineWidth=pJS.particles.line_linked.width;pJS.canvas.ctx.stroke();pJS.canvas.ctx.closePath();if(pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.enable){var o=t.x-r.x,n=t.y-r.y,q=o/(pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateX*1000),p=n/(pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateY*1000);r.vx+=q;r.vy+=p}}};pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.listeners=function(){if(pJS.interactivity.detect_on=="window"){var m=window}else{var m=pJS.canvas.el}m.onmousemove=function(p){if(m==window){var o=p.clientX,n=p.clientY}else{var o=p.offsetX||p.clientX,n=p.offsetY||p.clientY}if(pJS){pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x=o;pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y=n;if(pJS.retina){pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x*=pJS.canvas.pxratio;pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y*=pJS.canvas.pxratio}pJS.interactivity.status="mousemove"}};m.onmouseleave=function(n){if(pJS){pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x=0;pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y=0;pJS.interactivity.status="mouseleave"}};if(pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.enable){switch(pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.mode){case"push":m.onclick=function(o){if(pJS){for(var n=0;n<pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.nb;n++){pJS.particles.array.push(new pJS.fn.particle(pJS.particles.color_rgb,pJS.particles.opacity,{x:pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,y:pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y}))}}};break;case"remove":m.onclick=function(n){pJS.particles.array.splice(0,pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.nb)};break}}};pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.grabParticles=function(r,q){var u=r.x-q.x,s=r.y-q.y,p=Math.sqrt(u*u+s*s);var t=r.x-pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,n=r.y-pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y,o=Math.sqrt(t*t+n*n);if(p<=pJS.particles.line_linked.distance&&o<=pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance&&pJS.interactivity.status=="mousemove"){var m=pJS.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line;pJS.canvas.ctx.beginPath();pJS.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle="rgba("+m.r+","+m.g+","+m.b+","+(pJS.interactivity.line_linked.opacity-o/pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance)+")";pJS.canvas.ctx.moveTo(r.x,r.y);pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y);pJS.canvas.ctx.lineWidth=pJS.particles.line_linked.width;pJS.canvas.ctx.stroke();pJS.canvas.ctx.closePath()}};pJS.fn.vendors.destroy=function(){cancelAnimationFrame(pJS.fn.requestAnimFrame);i.remove();delete pJS};function f(){pJS.fn.canvasInit();pJS.fn.canvasSize();pJS.fn.canvasPaint();pJS.fn.particlesCreate();pJS.fn.particlesDraw()}function l(){pJS.fn.particlesDraw();pJS.fn.requestAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(l)}f();if(pJS.particles.anim.enable){l()}if(pJS.interactivity.enable){pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.listeners()}}window.requestAnimFrame=(function(){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(a){window.setTimeout(a,1000/60)}})();window.cancelRequestAnimFrame=(function(){return window.cancelAnimationFrame||window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame||window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame||window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame||clearTimeout})();function hexToRgb(c){var b=/^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;c=c.replace(b,function(e,h,f,d){return h+h+f+f+d+d});var a=/^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(c);return a?{r:parseInt(a[1],16),g:parseInt(a[2],16),b:parseInt(a[3],16)}:null}particlesJS=function(d,c){if(typeof(d)!="string"){c=d;d="particles-js"}if(!d){d="particles-js"}var b=document.createElement("canvas");b.style.width="100%";b.style.height="100%";var a=document.getElementById(d).appendChild(b);if(a!=null){launchParticlesJS(d,c)}};

// No cargar en dispositivos moviles, hacer un condicional con el width
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ancho = $(window).width();

  if(ancho > 10){

    particlesJS('particles-js', {
      particles: {
        color: '#FF5722',
        shape: 'circle', // "circle", "edge" or "triangle"
        opacity: 1,
        size: 4,
        size_random: true,
        nb: 20,
        line_linked: {
          enable_auto: true,
          distance: 100,
          color: '#FF5722',
          opacity: 1,
          width: 1,
          condensed_mode: {
            enable: false,
            rotateX: 600,
            rotateY: 600
          }
        },
        anim: {
          enable: true,
          speed: 2
        }
      },
      interactivity: {
        enable: true,
        mouse: {
          distance: 300
        },
        detect_on: 'canvas', // "canvas" or "window"
        mode: 'grab',
        line_linked: {
          opacity: .5
        },
        events: {
          onclick: {
            enable: true,
            mode: 'push', // "push" or "remove"
            nb: 4
          }
        }
      },
      /* Retina Display Support */
      retina_detect: true
    });
  }
  
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family:oswald, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position:0 0px;
 background:rgb(0,0,0,0);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.contenedor {
 width: 90%;
 max-width:1000px;
 margin:auto;
}

#particles-js {
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 position: fixed;
 background:black;
}

header {
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Particulas</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="particles-js">
  
  <h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:100px;">Lovi acabados</h1>

 </div>
 


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="particles.min.js"></script>
 <script src="particulas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El texto aparece pero está en negro (por defecto). Simplemente dale un `color: white` al texto para que se vea con el fondo.

Comment: eso lo se que el texto por defecto es negro pero si vistes bien el texto estaba arriba del efecto me gustaria que el texto estuviera sobre el, me entiendo?

Comment: ¿Te refieres en medio de la página? ¿O en algún sitio concreto? ¿O simplemente que se superpusiera a los elementos naranjas?

Comment: me gustaria que el texto este en el centro de el efecto matrix y que el fondo de ese texto fuera ese efecto.

Comment: ¿Era [eso que buscabas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76500/2089) @gilbertoquintero ?

Comment: Si gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si [esta es la biblioteca](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js) que está utilizando para crear este efecto, puede hacerlo así:

> Lo nuevo elemento HTML `#particleWrapper` tanto como su CSS puede no ser necesario, dependiendo de cómo se construye su página. Usted decide qué es mejor para su estructura.

### HTML:

```
<!-- agrega un wrapper para asegurarse de que el título no se salga del área de partículas -->
<div id="particleWrapper">

    <!-- particles.js container -->
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <!-- particles title creado -->
    <h1 class="particle-title">Lovi acabados</h1>

</div>
```

### CSS:

```
/* particles container */
#particleWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw; /* puedes cambiar este valor por lo que desea en px */
    height: 100vh; /* puedes cambiar este valor por lo que desea en px */
}

/* particles title */
.particle-title {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    /* Centra el texto tanto vertical como horizontalmente */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Se asegura de que no hay eventos de puntero, por lo que cuando se pasa el texto el efecto sigue funcionando y no está bloqueado */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

### Aquí abajo tienes una demostración en vivo. Clica en el botón `Mostrar fragmento de código`:

```js
/* ---- particles.js config ---- */

particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 380,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#FF5722"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#FF5722",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
```

```css
/* ---- reset ---- */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* (NEW) particles wrapper */
#particleWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

/* (NEW) particles title */
.particle-title {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  /* Centra el texto tanto vertical como horizontalmente */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  /* Se asegura de que no hay eventos de puntero, por lo que cuando se pasa el texto el efecto sigue funcionando y no está bloqueado */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

<!-- (NEW) agrega un wrapper para asegurarse de que el título no se salga del área de partículas -->
<div id="particleWrapper">

  <!-- particles.js container -->
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <!-- (NEW) particles title creado -->
  <h1 class="particle-title">Lovi acabados</h1>
  
</div>
```